# Multiple Pickerview with differents values

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uipickerview

I have 5 tables, and I have to make an UIPickerView for each one.

I created one, like this

How can I do with the 4 others table ? I have to make 4 copy of this code ?

I do not know if I'm the right way to create my UIPickerView , I would like confirmation (or not).
This is what I did (I took the code from my colleague, who is also a beginner)

This is the right way to do ?

How to adapt it if I UIPickerViews 5 ?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *pickerViewDossier;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.pickerViewDossier = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview:self.pickerViewDossier];

UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.delegate = self;

self.pickerViewDossier.inputView = pickerView;

UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Valider" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneTouched:)];

UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Annuler" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancelTouched:)];

[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton, [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil], doneButton, nil]];

self.pickerViewDossier.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

self.listeSuiviDossier = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Vous-même", @"Un confrère",nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
return listeSuiviDossier.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
NSString *titrePickerview = listeSuiviDossier[row];
return titrePickerview;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
NSString *titrePickerview = listeSuiviDossier[row];
[suiviDossierBouton setTitle:titrePickerview forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (IBAction)suiviDossierAction:(id)sender {
[self.pickerViewDossier becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)cancelTouched:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
[self.pickerViewDossier resignFirstResponder];
[suiviDossierBouton setTitle:@"Sélectionnez" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)doneTouched:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
[self.pickerViewDossier resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tag for picker so that you can select what to do for each picker.

For example:

Where you are Declaring your pickers:

```
picker1.tag = 1
picker2.tag = 2
```

and for each method:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger) { 
    if(pickerView.tag == 1) // you can also use a switch
     {
          // picker 1
     }
     else if(pickerView.tag == 2)
     {
          // picker 2
     }
     else if(pickerView.tag == 3)
     {
          // picker 3
     }     
     else if(pickerView.tag == 4)
     {
          // picker 4
     }
}
```

Comment: How do you do this please, can you give me an example please ? :)

Comment: Thnaks bro' :) I will test it

Comment: I still have a problem, I edited my first post , can you look and tell me what you think of it please?